# How to perform a case in-sensitive search on a case sensitive MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

How to perform a case in-sensitive search on a case sensitive MySQL database?
For example, **name = Test & name = test**.
then the query returns both Test & test.
How to make a query for this..??

Comment: You can handle this at query level as well. Pls go through, I already have explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179123/mysql-how-to-do-a-case-sensitive-search/52511482#52511482

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(name) = '" . strtolower($name) . "'";
```

Comment: NO NO!! No variable appending directly to the query! No!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
select * from your_table
where `name` = 'test'
COLLATE latin1_general_ci
```

or

```
select * from your_table
where `name` = 'test'
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: FYI, the naming convention for collation in MySQL is:

`*_bin`: binary case sensitive
`*_cs`: case sensitive
`*_ci`: case insensitive

The default is typically a case-insensitive collation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html

Comment: @vinu: Maybe you are using another collation in your MySQL installation. Have you tried `utf8_unicode_ci`?