# Mysql - How to do a case sensitive search?

Tags: mysql

I have 4cci and 4ccI values in database. When I run this query I get both rows.

```
   select * from urls where url = "4cci";
```

How to do a case sensitive search?

Comment: Interesting. That is _not_ the default behavior you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Depend on your text field collation

Check the **[manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html)**

```
mysql> SET @s1 = 'MySQL' COLLATE latin1_bin,
    ->     @s2 = 'mysql' COLLATE latin1_bin;
mysql> SELECT @s1 = @s2;

+-----------+
| @s1 = @s2 |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use keyword **BINARY** before the column you want to perform case sensitive search

Description :

The BINARY function converts a value to a binary string.

Example

Suppose we have one table stores with 3 records where two recoard have country column as "IN" and one has as "in"

```
select count(*) from stores where BINARY country = 'in';
```

**Output** : count : 1

OR

Use **CAST()** function :

Description :

Convert a value to a DATE datatype:

```
   select count(*) from stores where CAST(country AS BINARY) = 'IN';
```

**Output** : count : 2

**How these function works :**

Understand with simple example :

```
SELECT BINARY "HELLO" = "hello";
```

**Output** : 0

Here MySQL performs a byte-by-byte comparison of  "HELLO" and "hello" and return 0 (because on a byte-by-byte basis, they are NOT equivalent):